# Windows Phone xaudio2

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8, encode, xaudio2, adpcm

Hej

I am using a library for playing audio in Windows Phone found [here.](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.dk/2012/12/c-xaudio2-sound-playback-for-windows.html)
Which works fine.

I am then trying to add a new .wav file to this system. And I get a memory error. Searching around on the internet gives me that I have to encode the audio using AdpcmEncode command-line tool. However using this tool cannot convert my .wav files. Can anyone help here, regarding encoding to get the audio working?

Furthermore just for my information how big can my audio files be? I think I read some place 20 mb, but unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoding is a bitch. Even with me having the tool and .wav files I did not succeed in getting audio played. From new .wav files that was not included.

But finally I succeeded and seems there is no problem with big audio files 100mb.

So what I needed to do was to first run the audio file through a program called Free Audio Converter. And then use the cmd line tool Adpcmencode, and it was possible to use in the sample project.