# Windows phone - Audio api

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, audio

I am doing a windows phone application based on audio mixing and audio effects. In that following tasks are to be done.

1. **Tracks with different sound**

   In a page i have to list name of tracks(Audio) with slider control for each track. User can adjust volume level using slider for every track. Once user completes volume adjustment  and clicks play button, i have to play all the tracks simultaneously with corresponding sound levels.
2. **Echo, Frequency changing effect**

   User can add echo effect for audio and also can change frequency.
3. **Background Noise Sensor**

   Cancel background noise.
4. **Download mixed track from a link**

   After doing all the above, user can send a link to mail id. If that link is clicked audio should get downloaded.

After searching got details about *XAudio2* and trying that. Is there any other native or third party tools to do all these tasks or some tasks?

Answer (score 1):

As you state XAudio2 is the way to go, if you are put of with the c++ code you need to do, I would recommend this [link](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.dk/2012/12/c-xaudio2-sound-playback-for-windows.html) for getting started it is a small sample program that interfaces the c++ dll to your c# code, and is a small sample of how to  play sounds simultaneously.

From here you need to create your audios so they can be played by XAudio2, done by use of [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415711(v=vs.85).aspx) and what I found in a question I had [Windows Phone xaudio2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780644/windows-phone-xaudio2).

The other points you have are possible in XAudio2, you can find API's and help [here on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh405049(v=vs.85).aspx)

Regarding your download, you need to interface with a server, maybe Azure? here you can save a stream, as you can save an audio stream to the phone. However there is issue with data usage, that users should be aware of.

Finally for music apps You need to upheld to certain Windows Phone criterions stated in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184838(v=vs.105).aspx) and a [walk through](http://henry-chong.com/2012/02/pro-tip-including-background-music-for-your-windows-phone-app/).

Just my ideas and suggestions :)