# How to play muted video and mp3-track simultaneously with c# Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I need to play [short looped video (mp4) without sound] and [mp3-file] simultaneously.

I tried to create 2 MediaElements: for audio and video, but WindowsPhone can play only one MediaElement in one time.

Do you know any tricks how to play video and audio simultaneously?

Maybe there are other ways to play mp3 or video (no MediaElement)?

SoundEffect can play only WAV-files, so this way is not for me, because all my files are MP3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to try and use xaudio2 for the music. At least there i can play multiple songa simuntaneously

Comment: JTIM, could you give link to example howto play MP3 with xaudio2? Google wasn't very helpful

Comment: I answered with what information I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my issue using MediaStreamSource!

1. Create 2 Streams:

   - from mp3-file for audio
   - from mp4-file for video
2. Create new class from MediaStreamSource
3. override OpenMediaAsync() - return video-info from Stream with mp4,
   audio-info from Stream with mp3
4. override GetSampleAsync(MediaType) - if MediaType is Video - return
   mp4-sample, else - return mp3 sample

It works!

Ps: Links for examples:

- HowTo pars MP3: https://github.com/loarabia/ManagedMediaHelpers
- HowTo pars MP4: https://mediastreamsources.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

As first way is to use MediaElement so keep it as it is.

Secondly, you have two options,

1) you can make use of MediaPlayer if your mp3 is stored locally i.e. stored in   isolatedstorage/medialibrary

2) you can use BackgroundAudioPlayer if your mp3 is located at specific server.

Hope this Helps.

Comment: My mp3-files are located in Internet. I tried to use BackgroundAudioPlayer but this way has the same problem: when music is playing video is stoped, when I use .play() for video, music is stoping (

Answer (score 0):

For using Xaudio2 you can look into this link, [download sample](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.dk/2012/12/c-xaudio2-sound-playback-for-windows.html).

One problem can be with the music files, I am unsure now that I think about it if mp3 will work. But you can play music in the background of everything with it. If you have trouble with the formatting, there is this link [Windows Phone xaudio2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780644/windows-phone-xaudio2) where I had the format problem, with wav files. But see if you can get it to work :)

Comment: I was trying to win Xaudio2, but could not do it ... Its to hard for MP3 :(